# Create flattened array by mapping arrays

Tags: javascript

I have the following array or arrays:

```
const aa = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  ... could be more here
];
```

I would like to create an array that looks like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I currently have:

```
const result = aa.map(a => [...a]);
```

and `result` is:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I know how to flatten the array using:

```
var flattenedArray = [].concat(...result);
```

but I just wondered whether I could have done anything different in the `map` to create the result I want without the extra "flattening" step?

Comment: `.map()` translates every element of an array. The number of elements before and after `.map()` will be the same.

Comment: Your `.map()` step is essentially a no-op; you end up with an identical nested array.

Comment: It's impossible to flatten an array using `map()`. It always returns an array of the same length as the original, whereas with flattening produces an array of a different length.

Answer (score 1):

#### Execute the `join` function and then parse the result using `parse` function.

```js
const aa = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

console.log(JSON.parse(`[${aa.join()}]`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

#### Also, you can use the `Spread operator`

```js
const bb = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

let newArray = [], 
    i = bb.length;
    
while (i --> 0) newArray = [...newArray, ...bb[bb.length - i - 1]];

console.log(newArray);
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Spread operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: This returns a string, not an array

Answer (score 1):

If you use `reduce()` instead of `map()` you could do this in one step.

```js
const aa = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6]
];

const result = aa.reduce((r, e) => [...r, ...e] , []);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Reduce is unnecessary. This does the same thing: `[].concat(...nested)`

Comment: @greim Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a check and concat the mapped flatted arrays to a new array.

```js
var flat = a => [].concat(...(Array.isArray(a) ? a.map(flat) : [a])),
    array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, [6, 7, 8]]],
    result = flat(array);

console.log(result);
```